# How do I resolve this apparent Catch22

Tags: wpf, vb.net, custom-controls

I have a wpf custom control with (as is common) a shared constructor.  This one looks like this;

```
Shared Sub New()
    'This OverrideMetadata call tells the system that this element wants to provide a style that is different than its base class.
    'This style is defined in Themes\Generic.xaml
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(VtlDataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(VtlDataNavigator)))

    ItemsSourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(VtlDataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf OnItemsSourceHasChanged))
End Sub
```

The control inherits ItemsControl and I want to have notification of when the itemsSource changes hence the second line in the constructor.  OnItemsSourceHasChanged needs to be a shared sub in order for the line in the constructor to compile. Fine.

In the shared sub I have the following:

```
  Private Shared Function OnItemsSourceHasChanged(d As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) As Object
    RecordCount = Items.SourceCollection.Cast(Of Object)().Count()
End Function
```

which of course fails to compile because you cannot refer to an instance method of a class from within a shared method without creating a specific instance of the class.  Even If a create a separate non shared handler for this I will still end up with the same error when trying to call it.

In essence all I want is the total RecordCount from the ItemsSource (hence my need to know when it's changed) so that I can then assign that value to RecordCount.  However what I appear to have instead is the proverbial catch 22 of errors.

The answer is probably staring me in the face, but for now it escapes me. Any Ideas?

Comment: In this case the `d` parameter is the control, so you simply need to cast `d` to `VtlDataNavigator` and use it's `Items.SourceCollection...` property.

Comment: Thank you Mike , had  a feeling it was staring me in the face but it's been a long day!